# Gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer um junção de duas tabelas no Django Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django

*Olá amigos, estou tendo uma leve dificuldade em como gerar um terceiro Model dentro do Django, atualmente eu tenho duas tabelas Treinamento e Entidade gostaria de saber se seria possível criar um outro app e fazer a junção dessas duas tabelas.*

Meu codigo é :

Pasta Treinamento/models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from phone_field import PhoneField
from localflavor.br.forms import BRZipCodeField
from datetime import time


# Create your models here.

class Treinamento(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome_treinamento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    conteudo =  models.TextField()
    requisito = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    recursos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    carga_horaria = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    local = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_treinamento
```

Pasta Entidade/models

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from phone_field import PhoneField
from datetime import time


# Create your models here.
class Entidade(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome_entidade = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    codigo_sap = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    pessoa_contato = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False, unique=True, error_messages={'required': 'Porfavor digite seu e-mail.', 'unique': 'Já existe esse e-mail cadastrado.'},)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Seu numero de telefone')
    cep = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    endereço = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data_registro = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_entidade
```

Comment: Explique melhor, do jeito q está parece n fazer sentido, qual seria o objetivo? O que vc quer como resultado? P/ q juntar as duas?

Comment: Olá Sidon, meu objetivo é criar uma aplicação que otimize uma tabela do excel e para isso preciso de 2 models um para o treinamento que a pessoa vai dar e uma para a pessoa que vai fazer o treinamento que eu nomeei como entidade, tendo isso em vista queria saber como posso gerar uma 3 tabela com a junção dos campos dessas duas tabelas, se eu consigo importar um model de uma app em outra app do meu projeto enfim qual solução existe para isso?

Comment: Sim vc pode importar os modelos entre as app,tipo: `from app.models import mymodel`, agora... "juntar" as tabelas? Não consigo ver o motivo, com as duas tabelas vc pode extrair as informações das duas da forma que desejar/necessitar, p/ criar mais uma?

Comment: Isso, vou lhe mostrar eu tenho os campos na tabela entidade que seria meu cliente:        [ Id_Entidade |Nome| Razão Social | Código SAP| Pessoa Contato | E-mail | Telefone | Endereço | CEP | Cidade | Estado| Data Registro]

E tenho os campos da minha tabela Treinamento :
[Id_treinamento | Treinamento | Categoria | Conteúdo| Requisitos| Recursos | Carga Horária | Tipo | Local]

E minha terceira tabela séria a interseção das duas com o nome de evento: ID_evento | Registro Treinamento | Registro Entidade | Valor | Data | Consulta | Data Realização | Registro Cotação |

Comment: em um banco de dados ORM  eu iria ter que fazer uma views com a INTERSECT das duas tabelas para gerar um relatório. mas eu estou querendo fazer isso no Django que é um banco de dados MVC é póssivel?

Comment: Reveja seus conceitos, um ORM não é um tipo de banco de dados, um ORM (object relational mapping) é um mecanismo para mapear um banco nao OO em classes OO e sim, o django usa um ORM para isso.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @LinikerOliveira o que vc quer dizer com juntar? como foi dito em um outro comentário vc pode fazer o import de outras tabelas de outros apps normalmente, essa junção ficaria em qual app? treinamento ou entidade? assim vc pode criar uma outra classe e herdar essas duas mas acho que não ficaria legal já que alguns campos poderiam ter conflitos

Comment: @LinikerOliveira o campo id não precisa ser colocado, o Django já faz isso pra vc ;)

Comment: @DaviWesley, comecei tudo de novo o meu projeto, agora irei criar uma tabela dentro de um só Model, porém estou com uma dúvida referente a onde eu posso mostrar a junção de dois campos de tabelas diferentes ( pois estou usando o Foreing Key mas ele dá vários erros) a visualização eu preciso fazer no controller?

Comment: @LinikerOliveira tudo bem? então, vc pode criar um atributo na sua classe que chama alguma propriedade algum modelo e fazer a lógica que vc queira, veja este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379587/django-whats-the-difference-between-a-model-field-and-a-model-attribute#33379814)

Comment: @Davi Wesley muito obrigado pela orientação, tive algumas ideias e fiz tudo dentro de um app só. muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Ao invés de criar uma terceira tabela/model você poderia criar um único `formset` para manipular as duas tabelas/models em um único formulário. Veja mais sobre o `formset` em: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/